# Winform memory spike

Tags: winforms, memory

I have the following issue. I have deployed a smart client application to several users. Memory usage is adequate for all of them except one. For this particular user the memory usage is 2 to 2 1/2 times the usage than for any other user. The desktop specs are the same as for the other users. The computer was defragged not long ago. I was wondering If anyone had any insights on why would this be happening. Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: ahhh...good point...didn't try that route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an answer, but a few ideas on how you can attack the problem.

1. What is different about this user? 64bit os, windows version, the data they are accessing
2. Do you have logging and profiling in place. Watch/record their usage, so that you can "replay" it.
3. Are they using the application for long periods (in particular longer than the other users), you may have objects that are being garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.NET memory profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) to troubleshoot this type of issue.  It will give you a very good snapshot of the memory usage of your .NET application.